# join 2 csv files into third file with "|" as seperator

Tags: linux, join

I want to join two files

### a.csv

```
customer|BillTo
100|3437146
103|3436977
```

### b.csv

```
Customer|Parent
100|ANHEUSER-BUSCH INBEV
1025|INTRASTATE DISTRIBUTORS INC.
```

The joined file should be like this

```
Parent|BillTo
ANHEUSER-BUSCH INBEV|3437146
```

I tried to use awk but seems can't get the result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out *nix's `join` command, [Here's a tutorial](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to use  join -1 2 -1 2 -t '|' <(sort a.csv) <(sort b.csv) but it seems not like the sorting. also, i have filed name in the file and i want to keep. not able to figure it out.

Comment: you have to sort the file so the keys you are using (in your code, that would be field # `2`) are in order. But, think about the values found in field #`2` in each of those files, I don't think you can get them to match. Which field has the matchable values? Change your `join` command to reflect that. AND read about the `-o` option for `join`. Good luck.

Comment: i need to sort "Customer", that's filed #1 right?

Comment: also i need header there. after i sort it, even "join a.csv b.csv" (because the first column is the key for both files, so i think i can do this simple one base on the tutorial) not giving any result.

Comment: typically, people delete the header and then put it back after the sorting. There are many many versions of this Q already here on S.O. Try searching for `[bash] join header`. Good luck.

Comment: "I need to sort 'Customer' ... ", Right. And you have designed your problem correctly in that you have a very tiny data set to test with. You can easily `sort file1` and let the output appear on your terminal. Then you can change an option to `sort` and see what the new output looks like. Same  your your `join` command. Got to go. I won't be back until tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your help. the data set i put here is a sample, the real files are much longer than this. i will check online based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ join -j1 --header -o 2.2,1.2 -t'|' \
   <(head -n 1 a.csv; tail -n +2 a.csv | sort) \
   <(head -n 1 b.csv; tail -n +2 b.csv | sort)
Parent|BillTo
ANHEUSER-BUSCH INBEV|3437146
```

This assumes GNU `join`, which since you have this tagged linux seems a safe bet, and a shell like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`, etc. that supports `<(command)` style redirection (`/bin/sh` usually doesn't).

Comment: GNU `sort` really could use a `--header` option to skip sorting the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. when i run the join, i got the this :
|BillTo
|3437146-BUSCH INBEV

Comment: @Xiaoning Then your files are different from what you have in your question.

Comment: i fond the output file is overlapped some how on columns, it mix the "Parent" and "BIllTo". both the header and row,

Comment: @Xiaoning I bet your files have Windows style line endings and you're working on a different OS with Unix style line endings. I get that output after running `unix2dos` on the sample files.

Comment: You are exactly right, Yes, i am using Ubuntu in Windows for this testing. Thanks.

Comment: your suggestion works perfect! thanks, one more question, if i want to specify the column to match, in my case, i want to use "customer" and "Parent" to join (for example) how do i change this command?